# lassen and its usages and meanings

Tags: verb, sentence-structure

How is the distribution of objects?

Example:

> "Die Soldaten haben sich töten lassen."

There is one or more object after "haben", they can be one of the following:

- object for lassen,
- object for töten,
- subject for töten.

*How to differentiate between them? Based on place and order?*

**X hat Y K töten lassen.**

- X is subject of lassen,
- Y is object of lassen and subject of töten,
- K is object of töten.

*Now some variations:*

**Die Soldaten haben sich töten lassen.**

Is here "sich"

- object of lassen and subject of töten

*OR*

- object of töten?

In English:

- They permitted themselves to kill.
- vs: They permitted others to kill them.

---

**Die Soldaten haben die Zivilisten töten lassen**

- civilians are object of lassen and subject of töten

*OR*

- object of töten.

How do you do the difference between it?

Comment: So: where is your question? Yes, they are all distinct meanings of lassen, and some of your sentences are right but others are wrong.... What do you expect to be answered? Please ask distinct questions that can be answered one by one.... as is I vote to close as unclear what you are asking..

Comment: ok, here is more exact:

Comment: @orodeous: I tried to make it a bit more structured - it is just that I have no idea if I still meet your intentions. If you reorder I'd prefer to keep some things like capital letters.

Comment: Yuo did it good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

As a German native speaker, I consider

> Die Soldaten haben sich töten lassen.

as to be (theoretically) translatable into

> They permitted others to kill them.

But I think this is just a "flowery" description for the passive construction "were killed".

For an official reasoning, i.e. the *long answer*, I have to think for a while ...

Comment: Die Konstruktion *sich etwas machen lassen* wird im Englischen mit *to have/get something done*. Demnach müsste *Die Soldaten haben sich töten lassen* so etwas wie *The soldiers got themselves killed* sein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ja, die obige "Übersetzung" ist ja mehr die Konstruktionsvorschrift für die Aussage. Deine Übersetzung ist völlig korrekt. Denkbar ist aber auch schlicht *The soldiers were killed.* Es handelt cih eben um eine Passiv-Kontruktion wie *ich lasse mich füttern* oder auch *er lässt sich bezahlen* -- aber es ist nicht auszuschließen, dass man in Lyrik auch von der anderen Interpretationsmöglichkeit gebrauch machen könnte ...

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences carry something *wrong*. Maybe the drastic content shows it more clearly. What otherwise could be a almost a joke suddenly gets dead serious:

> Die Soldaten haben sich töten lassen

Either they did not react/defend themselves or they got killed on their own fault. It is reflexive, so at least that part is clear. Put "einander" instead of "sich" and it gets quite absurd.

> Die Soldaten haben die Zivilisten töten lassen

This is even worse, because it can be taken in two completely different ways. "töten" can be without object or with "Zivilisten" as object.

This example is just confusing and macabre. I wonder if it really needs "töten" to work.

On the next page of that book will be a lengthy and very smart discussion of life and death of Schroedinger's Cat.

---

> Ich habe meinen Sklaven auspeitschen lassen.

The usual thing: make something happen. Unless you have a weird slave and allow him some time during  which he does some of his own whipping; but then: whom is he whipping? "auspeitschen" wants an object...something intransitive like "gehen lassen" would be better.

> Ich habe meinen Sklaven **mich** auspeitschen lassen.

Unlike "töten", "auspeitschen" can have a desirable and *funny* side. Here the speaker could be making the joke: partly I gave him the order, partly I had to let it happen. Now the ambiguity is intended.

---

Comment: Try for instance *`du hast dich abzocken lassen`*. That's not so macabre. I think you show an interesting point, the message *behind* the message.

Comment: Yes, but here the message is clear. The Abzockers are anonymous, the Abzockee is "du". You can force it into somthing else `Danke, dass du mich die anderen hast abzocken lassen`. I insert an object, because of the `ab-`. If you leave out the ab-, it changes from "cheat somebody" to "gamble".

Comment: I mean that the original sentence isn't ambiguous (for a German native speaker). It states that the soldiers are dead *and* that they didn't defend themselves successfully. It is not clear (since we have too little context) whether this sentence should additionally express an accusation or perhaps even malice.

Comment: This is where i totally disagree. `Die Soldaten wurden getötet` is the starting point (this is more precise than "are dead")  . We know nothing about any defense (or death wish); this somehow is implied by the 'lassen'. Of course context changes everything. I have nothing aginst analysing an officer complaining: `Die sind nicht gefallen, die haben sich einfach töten lassen`. This is how 'lassen' can be used, by the officer and the writer. That would be the message behing the message: look how the officers talk.

Comment: Sorry I was not precise enough here. I should have written *`It states that the soldiers were killed [...]`* instead of *`It states that the soldiers are dead [...]`*. You are absolutely right in this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think *subject for the infinite verb* is the answer, but I'm not sure what difference it makes. The surface syntax is clossest to *object raising*, "They want *us* to help".

I'd thus translate naively: *They have they [to] be killed*.

It's isn't the most felicite translation, obviously, this isn't elu.SE, but the grammar should be correct, theoreticly, and the fidelity is quite high. Maybe try "them" instead.

Don't confuse *sich* for *themselves*, that's just wrong. English simply has no reflex of *sik-, probably never had. Don't confuse *lassen* for *let*, either. Rather consider:

> They left their own to be killed.

This has to be ambiguous, for short, since the whole English language simply doesn't distinguish between inclusive and exclusive "we".